# Android device not receiving GCM push messages until network state changes

Tags: android, asp.net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented chat in my project and using GCM for it.In this i have came across the strange issue.

I have do following steps for it.

1. Send chat message to server.
2. Server fetches reg key of device and send push message to GCM server.
3. Now on other device in which i am receiving push message i tried waiting for the push message for a long time.

But i did **not** receive the push message.

4. Now when i turn my wifi off and on it again or switch from 3g to wifi or vice-versa, i get all push messages at once.

I have read GCM docs and i also have seen these two questions in Stackoverflow.

- [Google Cloud Messaging - messages sometimes not received until network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835676/google-cloud-messaging-messages-sometimes-not-received-until-network-state-cha)
- [Device stops receiving GCM pushes until network is switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572067/device-stops-receiving-gcm-pushes-until-network-is-switched)

I have also referred a google groups question regarding this issue

[Problem in getting messages on device using GCM](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-gcm/bsYumo68fsc).

But i didn't get any solution till now.

I am using Asp.net at the server side.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I have came through it. Don't know what to do? Let me take help also. It's really urgent for me also

Comment: I know it is not an answer for your question but you can take it as hint, GCM does not guarantee delivering the message to the intended device, so why you don't use asmack which implemented xmpp protocol instead which will be more helpfull for your application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Messaging - messages sometimes not received until network state changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835676/google-cloud-messaging-messages-sometimes-not-received-until-network-state-cha)