# GCM Push messages being kept on the server until a new one arrives

Tags: java, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app using Google Cloud Messaging with the latest Google Play Services version.

If I turn my device's network connections off, all messages that should have been received during the time I have no Internet access are stored in the server, and I do not get them until a new one arrives when I have turned one of my network connections back on.

So, if I receive 20 new messages during the night, when I have my WiFi/3G off, when I switch my WiFi on in the morning I get no messages, and when the first new message arrives I get the 21 push notifications at once.

The question is, then... is there any way around this? Is it a problem of my implementation or this is the expected behaviour and I should have to find some workaround?

Thanks!

**Small edit:** I do not get the 21 notifications at once, since the push messages I send are collapsible, but I do not get the collapsed message until a new one arrives, anyway.

Comment: Υou want to dispose those 20 messages or what?

Comment: No, I want to receive then when I turn my WiFi on again in the morning, without having to wait for a new one to arrive and then get them all together. Right now, if I don't get any messages in the morning, the 20 night messages are stuck in some kind of push message limbo :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835676/google-cloud-messaging-messages-sometimes-not-received-until-network-state-cha

Comment: Thank you Pavlos, I think it's not *exactly* the same problem, and anyway, I was hoping for some kind of workaround because, you know, lots of apps use push notifications and I get their messages in the morning, so either it's a problem with my implementation or there is some kind of workaround for it... anyway, thanks for the link!

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your current implementation, I've used push notifications and they arrive as soon as I get internet connection, can you post code to take a look?

Comment: Post your server-side code for adding parameters to the messages, it might be a problem with the time_to_live or delay_while_idle parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an issue of `time_to_live` parameter on the message payload. Quoting [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params) on the same:

> **time_to_live**: How long (in seconds) the message should be kept on GCM storage if the device is offline.(default time-to-live is 4 weeks).

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks! You were right, it **was** an issue with the `time_to_live` parameter. I was manually setting it to 2419200 and there seems to be a bug with that, because I just removed the parameter altogether and now it's working.

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: is collapse_key is same for all message or different for all all message because i try to set it same for all message then i got only a last message.