# Android Push Id not getting generated over 3G/4G network

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm woring on an Android app that generates GCM push Id at launch time.
A user reported to me that he is not getting the push ID generated when connected on 3G/4G network but works on WiFi.

Is this possible? If so, why?

Has anybody experienced an issue like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835676/google-cloud-messaging-messages-sometimes-not-received-until-network-state-cha) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi Thank you for your answer but this post explain issue about push messages, but my problem is about registering on google GCM servers and receiving the push token as response.